# How to check if an app name is available without taking it?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, app-store-connect

Is it possible to check if a name is available without choosing it ?
Since I am developing for android, wp8, and iOS at the same time, I wanted to check that the name is available on all three stores first ?

Comment: Do a search on corresponding Stores.

Comment: how do you do that without selecting the name? You can't use a search engine because some names may be blocked by apps that have not been released yet.

Comment: So you know all about that locking and all, then why are you asking such a question. Answer is simple : You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You cant check app name is available to you without entering it, Specially for iOS and WP8.

In android, You may choose same name of app if other developer has published already but package name should be different.

For iOS and WP8, if someone have already created app with that name and not released yet then you cant able to choose same name. And to check this scenario, you need to login in respective store's developer account and check name is available or not by filling required details.

I hope it may help you.